# ArcPy block statistics need to output different resolution

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro, resampling, block

I am attempting to script a `BlockStatistics` where the outRaster has a resolution different from the input raster. Input raster cells are approx 5.8 cm, and I want to resample taking the mean of a 30x30 window, returning approx resolution 1.7m x 1.7m. I can do this in ArcGIS Pro with `BlockStatistics` tool and changing environment to cell size to 1.772 but for the life of me cannot find where to change the environment for the tool using ArcPy. Also, if there is a simpler solution I am missing, I am open to it.

`OutRas` returned with the following code snippet calculates block statistics fine, but returns raster of 30x30 blocks with the identical mean calculations and original resolution.

```
OutRas = arcpy.sa.BlockStatistics(inRas, "Rectangle 30 30 Cell", "MEAN", "")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set environment settings with the [`arcpy.env`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/env.htm) object or the [`arcpy.EnvManager`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/envmanager.htm) context manager.  The cell size setting is [`cellSize`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/environment-settings/cell-size.htm).

```
arcpy.env.cellSize = 1.7
# Or
with arcpy.EnvManager(cellSize=1.7):
    do something
```